# Не происход присвание нового значения перемнной в С

Tags: c, pic, proteus

Объясните, почему не происходит присваивание нового значения переменной в языке С.
Использую MPLAB X и Proteus 8.6
Пишу программу на С для PIC 12F675. В ней необходимо изменять время задержки в зависимости от количества нажатий на кнопку.

Все компилируется прекрасно, но протеус сходит с ума и всинит, а в те моменты, когда работает, задержка составляет минимальное значение.
Проблемы с протеусом или кодом ?

Comment: Думаю, проблема спряталась в `some code`, где не инициализируется button_counter. Или происходят другие интересные вещи.

Comment: Инициализируется button_counter и другие переменные, т.к. проверял их на зажигание светодиода.

Comment: Откуда взялось утверждение, вынесенное в заголовок вопроса? С чего это вы взяли, что не происходит присваивания?

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, добавьте секцию **default:** в оператор **switch()**, тогда отладчику станет немного легче. Подозреваю, что значение переменной *button_counter* не соответствует указанному сейчас диапазону. Проверьте чему равно это значение перед свитчем. И еще, тип задан как unsigned char - Вы уверены, что Вы присваиваете числа от 1 до 10, а не символы от '1' до '9'? (да, отдельная песня если делать *button_counter* = '10';).

Этих вопросов не было бы, если бы был указан кусок кода задающий значение *button_counter* в Вашей программе.